# Storage of Vim documentation files

Tags: vim

Where in the filesystem is stored the documentation of *Vim* (the contents that is displayed when you type `:h something` in *Vim*?
Is everything in one place or are there exceptions? Can I find out via some command where is stored e.g. the documentation file of some plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
:set runtimepath
```

Documentation will be looked for in a doc/ directory using the directories specified in the runtimepath.

You can get more information by doing:

```
:he runtimepath
```

Answer (score 1):

If you download the src-tree, all documentations is in folder

```
vim/runtime/doc
```

Default installation folder is

```
usr/local/share/vim/vim73/doc/
```